# Not able to get the UnitPrice using MAP

Tags: apex, map, product, pricebookentry

I have a Custom object `Product_Quantity__c` and it has a lookup field for `Product`, when user going to select any of the Product from that lookup field in Visualforce page then what i need is that product's List Price will auto populate

However, i doing same thing for Product's ProductCode & description and it's working fine

i know ProductCode and Description are info of the Direct Product but List Price is info of the Product's PriceBookEntry

Can anyone tell me where i need to change in my code or what i have done wrong ?

Apex class :

```
mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>();
PriceBookEntry = new PricebookEntry();

public void retrieveproductInfo() {
    for(Product2 product : [SELECT Id, ProductCode, Description FROM Product2]) {
        mapProductIdToProduct.put(product.Id, product);
        mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry.put(product.Id, PriceBookEntry);
        system.debug('====MAP====='+mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry);
    }
    if(PrdQuantity.Product__c != Null){
        this.partNumber = mapProductIdToProduct.get(PrdQuantity.Product__c).ProductCode;
        this.Description = mapProductIdToProduct.get(PrdQuantity.Product__c).Description;
        this.ListPrice = mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry.get(PrdQuantity.Product__c).UnitPrice;
    }
}
```

Debug :

[image]

Comment: Can you output you got from debug statement. Does `mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry` have value?

Comment: @Reshma Please see updated Question, i have posted Debug log image as well

Comment: `PriceBookEntry` has no value. Then how will you get value for unit price. Add a `Pricebookentry` to `mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry`

Comment: You mean there is no Pricebookentry available in that Product ?

Comment: `mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry.put(product.Id, PriceBookEntry);` in this line how do you get value in 'PriceBookEntry'

Comment: @Reshma I have not much knowledge of MAP so, i did not get you...i tried it without using MAP and it worked for me `this.ListPrice = [SELECT Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Product2Id =: PrdQuantity.Product__c Limit 1].UnitPrice;`..Can you please help me do it with MAP ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52852/discussion-between-reshma-and-wanttobeacoder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a separate query to get `PriceBookEntry`.

```
for(PriceBookEntry entry : [SELECT Id, Product2Id, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry]) { 
    mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry.put(entry.Product2Id, entry); 
    system.debug('====MAP====='+mapPricebookEntryIdToPricebookEntry); 
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it's appearing StandardPrice not UnitPrice, Standard Price = 100 $ & List Price = 102 $